# "Dieses akademisches Transkript" or "Dieses akademische Transkript"

Tags: adjective-ending, demonstrative-pronoun

Dieses akademisches Transkript

or

Dieses akademische Transkript

I know that I should add "s" to the end of the pronoun "dies" when the noun comes after it, and the noun should be singular, neutral and in nominative or accusative case,  but the question is should I also add "s" to the end of the adjective "akademisch" that comes in between?

Comment: This is listed in a [declension table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/akademisch). Check the positive forms of akademisch, you need the strong declension because you use it with a definite article ("dieses").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Adjective declination](https://www.learn-german-smarter.com/learn-german-adjective-endings/) depends on gender (der, die, das), tense (accusative, dative, genitive) AND on the pronoun you use.

In your case: neutral noun, nominative, definite pronoun. So:

> dieses akademische Transkript

Note that in this specific case nominative and accusative forms are identical:

> Dieses akademische Transkript enthält hilfreiche Daten.

und

> Ich habe mir dieses akademische Transkript angeschaut.

Answer (score 1):

`Dieses akademische Transkript` is the correct one because of adjective declension. You can read more on this topic [here](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/adjektive/deklination).

In this case: Neutral adjective in nominative case -> `akademische` rather than `akademisches`

Comment: Can you please explain why it's correct and/or link to a resource, where to look it up?